# How to use multiple wear os layouts and swap them programmatically

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to use a different layout on my wearable depending on the message from the mobile app. Example: if message type 1 comes in use data from message and populate controls (images/text) on layout 1 and present; if message type 2 comes in use layout 2 w/different set of controls and populate them with data from message 2.

Can I get some guidance on how to approach this? Is it different layouts? Is there any sample code for showing one and hiding another, or whatever the recommended approach for doing this is?

Answer (score 0):

This page of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions) might explain it best. The whole topic "Creating custom UIs" generally is relevant, since it works quite differently than on a regular mobile device, even if they share some layout & navigation concepts. Feel free to ask more specific questions, because as broad as it is, the best option is to direct you towards the documentation.

Comment: I read the documentation already. It did not seem to address the scenario I presented above. One screen for one type of message, one screen for another. They seemed to focus on scenarios with single screens with other UI elements like Action Drawers and lists. I didn't know if I could create a bunch of layouts and swap them programmatically depending on the message I received. This way I could use the interface tools to layout and see how things look for each. If this is some outlier approach.

Comment: @lcj most adapters support view-types, which permit inflating different layouts... while after all, this is still Android Java - therefore one can use one layout as container and then inflate whatever XML. the documentation shows what UI elements can be used & combined, and with the extremely limited screen-estate, one almost needs multiple views and some kind of navigation concept for them. the point is, that inflating does not support visual transitions. navigation also might be far more complicated than it would have to be - compared to some kind of pager. do not try to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and fastest is make two layouts in XML and set visibility programmatically in Java according to response.

```
view.setVisibility(View.Visible)

view.sertVisibility(View.Gone)
```

One thing while designing make 2 layouts in root layout and check alignments by hiding first, and then second.